# Is my mesh too complex?

Tags: export

So I got a toilet model from blendswap, since I needed a toilet for a house. I then tried importing that .fbx file to UE4, but it freezed. Looked it up, and the most common answer was that the mesh is probably high poly. So my question is, is it high poly? The toilet is just a background object.

The picture might help to explain the problem.

[image: the model]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your model is probably too detailed for a game scene background. Moreover, since it's a rather simplex geometry, the face count may be easily reduced with no noticeable effect on its appearance. As it was pointed out, you currently have almost 25,000 faces, that are unnecessarily too many for the surface of your toilet.

(Note: high-poly and low-poly mean high or low *polygon count*, polygons being your mesh's faces)

#### "Decimate" the number of faces

[image]

From the Properties window, Modifiers panel, click "Add modifier" and select "Decimate". Your face count is displayed as "*Faces: Xxxx*" on the bottom of the "Decimate" box.

The three methods (Collapse, Un-Subdivide and Planar) are described here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html

To see any effect, you must:

- on "Collapse", reduce the ratio (try something around 0.33: it'll reduce the face count by two thirds)
- on "Un-Subdivide", increase the number of iterations to 1 or 2
- on "Planar", change the threshold angle to 3-4 degrees.

(choose one of the three, whichever looks the best)

When you change these values, you can see the updated number of faces updated under your slider. Also, your model gets updated live in the 3D-view. Choose the lowest number of faces that still keeps the appearance good and smooth enough.

Once you are done, hit "Apply" in the decimate box.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too high poly for most computers, but try a lower poly model anyway. If it works then yes, it probably is too high poly for your computer.

Answer (score -1):

The face count is displayed in your window's header: in your scene there are just two objects with a total face count of 24,552 (which is quite a large number). Also, it's evident from the image that you have a high-poly mesh.

Comment: 24 thousand faces is not that super high value to freeze game engine. If there were 10 toilets imported at once then it might be.

Comment: Also UE4 4.14 added run time auto LOD for static meshes. As long as there aren't a bunch of toilets near each other, they should be fine from a distance. 24K should not be enough to crash UE4. (Though there is no reason to have this toilet be 24K)